# DB recommendation - Portable, Concurrent (multiple read only, one write)

Tags: database, .net-core, portability, webapi

I'm looking for a portable database solution I can use with a website that is designed to handle service outages. I need to nightly retrieve a list of users from SQL Server and upsert their details into a portable database.  It's roughly about 250,000 users (and growing) and each one has probably 25 fields that are required.  Of those fields, i'd say less than 5 need to be searched on. The rest just need retrieving.

The idea is, in times of a service outage, we can use a website that's designed to work from the portable database rather than SQL Server. Our long term goal, is to move to the cloud and handle things in an entirely different way, but for the short term this is our aim.

The website is going to be a .Net Core web api so will be being accessed by multiple users in multiple threads.  The website will only ever need read access, it will not be updating these details what-so-ever.

To keep the portable database up-to-date i'm thinking of having another application that just runs nightly to update the data.  Our business is 24 hours (albeit quieter overnight), so there is a potential this updater is in use while the website is in use.  While service outage would assume the SQL Server is down, this may not be the case. There are other factors in play that could cause what we would describe as outages.  This will be the only piece of software updating the database.

I've tried using LiteDB but I couldn't get it working in a way that worked with my concurrency requirements.  It did seem to do some of the job, and was easy to get running. However, i'd often run into locked files due to the nature of web api.  I did work out a solution for that, but then the updater app couldn't access the database file.

Does anyone have any recommendations I can look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the description of the problem (1 table, 250k rows with - I assume - relative fast growth rate) and requirements, I don't think a relational database is what you are looking for.

I think nosql databases, or, more specifically, document oriented databases are more fitted to meet your requirements. There are many choices: Mongo, Cassandra, CouchDB, ... the choice is yours.

Personally I have some experience with ElasticSearch (https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch), that is quite easy to learn, is portable (runs on Linux, Windows, Containers, etc...), is scalable, and it is fast. I mean, really, really fast, you can get results in 10-20 milliseconds (even less, sometimes).

The NEST nuget package acts as a high level client for working with ElasticSearch (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/nest-getting-started.html)